# Dynamic Programming, choosing the highest total value

Tags: dynamic-programming

The Data: 
A list of integers increasing in order (0,1,2,3,4,5.......)
A list of values that belong to those integers. As an example, 0 = 33, 1 = 45, 2 = 21, ....etc.

And an incrementing variable x which represent a minimum jump value.

x is the value of each jump. For example if x = 2, if 1 is chosen you cannot choose 2.

I need to determine the best way to choose integers, given some (x), that produce the highest total value from the value list.

EXAMPLE:

```
A = a set of 1 foot intervals (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
B = the amount of money at each interval (9,5,7,3,2,7,8,10,21,12)
Distance = the minimum distance you can cover
- i.e. if the minimum distance is 3, you must skip 2 feet and leave the money, then you can
pick up the amount at the 3rd interval. 

if you pick up at 0, the next one you can pick up is 3, if you choose 3 you can 
next pick up 6 (after skipping 4 and 5). BUT, you dont have to pick up 6, you 
could pick up 7 if it is worth more. You just can't pick up early. 

So, how can I programmatically make the best jumps and end with the most money at the end?
```

Comment: can you please add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am using the below equation for computing the opt value in the dynamic programming:

Here d is distance.

```
if (i -d) >= 0
opt(i) = max (opt(i-1), B[i] + OPT(i-d));

else 

opt(i) = max (opt(i-1), B[i]);
```

Psuedo-code for computing the OPT value:

```
int A[] = {integers list}; // This is redundant if the integers are consecutive and are always from 0..n.
int B[] = {values list};
int i = 0;
int d = distance; // minimum distance between two picks.
int numIntegers = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);

int opt[numIntegers];

opt[0] = B[0]; // For the first one Optimal value is picking itself.
for (i=1; i < numIntegers; i++) {

    if ((i-d) < 0) {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[i]);
    } else {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[i] + opt[i-d]);
    }

}
```

**EDIT based on OP's requirement about getting the selected integers from B:**

```
for (i=numIntegres - 1; i >= 0;) {
    if ((i == 0) && (opt[i] > 0)) {
        printf ("%d ", i);
        break;
    }
    if (opt[i] > opt[i-1]) {
        printf ("%d ", i);
        i = i -d;
    } else {
        i = i - 1;
    }

}
```

**If A[] does not have consecutive integers from 0 to n.**

```
int A[] = {integers list}; // Here the integers may not be consecutive
int B[] = {values list};
int i = 0, j = 0;
int d = distance; // minimum distance between two picks.
int numAs = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
int numIntegers = A[numAs-1]

int opt[numIntegers];

opt[0] = 0;
if (A[0] == 0) {
    opt[0] = B[0]; // For the first one Optimal value is picking itself.
    j = 1;
}

for (i=1; i < numIntegers && j < numAs; i++, j++) {
    if (i < A[j]) {
        while (i < A[j]) {
            opt[i] = opt[i -1];
            i = i + 1:
        }
    }

    if ((i-d) < 0) {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[j]);
    } else {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[j] + opt[i-d]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks so much

Comment: Now, what if I want to add the corresponding integers to a separate list to signify that they were the ones used for the total? For example, if 1, 3, 5 were the $$ chosen to make the max, how can i capture that?

Comment: yes, you can do that. give me 30  mins, I am doing something, I will add the code after that

Comment: yes, added the code to get the $$ chosen. It will print the integers from o..n that were selected.

Comment: Hey Sri, thanks so much, but I another request. The first array is important since it could be {0,1,5,6,9,14} for example, these are the only interval that have any money. When I do this, (i set the distance to 2) it gives the same output as {0,1,2,3,4,5} and it shouldnt. All but 0 OR 1 should be added. Sorry, I totally forgot that point when I posted the question. Thanks so much for the help so far.

Comment: That's doable with a minor change. I will update the code in the evening. I have some work in my lab now.

Comment: Ok. added the code for computing OPT when A does not have consecutive integers. The function for printing the selected ones, I edited in place because I had to change only one condition.